# php mysql_query returns empty value

Tags: php

I created a directory listing and came across this issue.

What value does `mysql_query($query1)` return if there is no value?

My script received this message from `$result`, would it be alright to pass `array(0)`?

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array($result) expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in
```

Comment: Post some code and finish your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: of course, that's some rough way to check the result of mysql_query. Better to show a meaningful error so that the user knows what happened. Also, the problem is not mysql_query failing (e.g. if the query is not well formed) but mysql_fetch_array failing because there are no results.

In that case `mysql_num_rows` does the job, as @nc3b pointed out

Comment: @nico  actually displaying the results of a mysql error is a information leakage vulnerability because it allows hackers to better identify sql injection flaws in your system.  However i posted it because its easy and to the point.

Comment: Rook: Sorry you may have misinterpreted what I was saying.
I was suggesting: `if (!mysql_query($query)) echo "Doh!!! I couldn't read the DB!! Click here to go back somewhere"` :)

I just don't like to put `die();` like that because the user will be stuck with a blank page not knowing what happened

Comment: @nico you could log the repose in a flat file.

Comment: Rook: Yeah, that's also another option. Depends on the situation, really. Do the users of your website want to fiddle around with flat files when an error occurs? Probably not (probably they can't either)

Answer (score 2):

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN
>   and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a
>   resource on success, or FALSE  on
>   error

If it doesn't return `FALSE`, you can use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to find out just how many rows were returned.